# Parallel Loop causes missing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I need to connect to a web service which does not accepts a list, so I had to implement a loop for the request.

However the normal for loop takes too long so I used a parallel loop instead,

```
    Parallel.For(0, myList.Count, (index) =>
    {
        customClass customClass = new customClass();
        customClass.Results = callWebservice(myList[index].data);
        tempHolder.Add(customClass);
    });
```

Compared to the normal loop, this is alot faster but it returns null in random results, why does this happen? Is sending too many request at once causing the jamming the web service

Comment: It is impossible to know why "it returns null". What happens in `callWebservice`? Maybe you are swallowing exceptions when you get at "to busy" results from the web service converting that into `null`? Also, the `tempHolder.Add(customClass)` is not thread safe so that may also be part of the problem.

Comment: mm thanks, i will look into the thread safe part